# Multi Language Setup for Shopware Test Environments

Tags: shopware6

When submitting an Extension to the Shopware store, we are provided a `sw-testenvironment.de` test store which has only one Storefront in Dutch configured.

In case we want to do our final test also with switching languages, how can we configure a multi-language environment on such an instance?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a /de and /du suffix to the sales channel, this will also enable the language switcher.

[image: Configuration screen with /de and /du suffix]